# CTE existence in memory

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have created 3 tables using CTE as follows:

```
;WITH Temp1(...)
AS
(...), Temp2
AS
(...), Temp3
AS
(...)
select * from Temp3;
```

I am curious about their existence in memory (or somewhere?), are Temp1 and Temp2 still in memory after Temp3 was created?

Comment: CTE's are similar to a sub-query. So after your select they aren't referenced anymore. However, SQL Server is designed to request as much RAM as possible which will not be released unless this memory is explicitly required by the operating system.

Comment: If your question is can you access the CTEs after that select the answer is no you can't.

Comment: There's no requirement that `Temp2` has to be based on `Temp1`, and `Temp3` on `Temp2` - any CTE can be referenced in the final `SELECT` statement and they may be completely independent.

Comment: Thanks, so 1 CTE is just the same as 10 CTEs in terms of performance in memory?

Comment: Performance-wise, stacking CTEs is just like doing a select from view which selects from view which selects from view... This can really slow thing down.

Comment: Ok, so we have to avoid using stacking CTE for big tables. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all exist within the scope of the `with` statement. 
You can easily prove this by selecting from them.

```
;with 
    temp1 as (...),
    temp2 as (select * from temp1),
    temp3 as (...)
select * from temp1 
union 
select * from temp2
union 
select * from temp3
```

Comment: yes, I have tried your advice and they all exist. Thank you!